# Camel file unit test

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel, I have written a simple route to scan a directory (/test), file will be processed when it was copied into the directory. Anyone has an idea on how to write a camel unit test to test the following route? Is there a way to mock the process of copying the file into the /test directory so that the route will be triggered.

```
public void configure() {
    from( "file:/test?preMove=IN_PROGRESS" + 
          "&move=completed/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}" + 
          "&moveFailed=FAILED/${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}" )
    .process(new Processor() {
          public void process(Exchange exchange) throws IOException {
              File file = (File) exchange.getIn().getBody();
              // read file content ......                 
          }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done the routing by one of many correct ways. But there exist some more important pieces to make your code run - you should create a context, create a router with this your `configure()`, add it to a context, and run this context.

Sorry, I prefer beans to processors, so you have also to register a bean. And make you processing a normal named method in a named class.

I think, the most compact info is [here](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html). JUnit test is a standalone app and you need to run Camel as a standalone app for JUnit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic idea is that you mock the end endpoint so you can check what is coming out your route. There are a few different ways, but you could test your route as follows:

```
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    private static final String INPUT_FILE = "myInputFile.xml";

    private static final String URI_START = "direct:start";

    private static final String URI_END = "mock:end";

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CamelTestConfig.class); // this is my Spring test config, where you wire beans
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        MyRoute route = new MyRoute();
        route.setFrom(URI_START); // I have added getter and setters to MyRoute so I can mock 'start' and 'end'
        route.setTo(URI_END);
        return route;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyRoute() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint result = getMockEndpoint(URI_END);
        context.start();

        // I am just checking I receive 5 messages, but you should actually check the content with expectedBodiesReceived() depending on what your processor does to the those files.

        result.expectedMessageCount(5);

        // I am just sending the same file 5 times
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            template.sendBody(URI_START, getInputFile(INPUT_FILE));
        }        

        result.assertIsSatisfied();
        context.stop();
    }

    private File getInputFile(String name) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        return FileUtils.getFile("src", "test", "resources", name);
    }
```

I am sure you already solved your issue is 2013, but this is how I would solve it in 2017. Regards

Comment: From where came the `template.sendBody` ?

Comment: ProducerTemplate https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html